# Hasse invariant of subalgebra of division algebra over local field

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4818241/hasse-invariant-of-subalgebra-of-division-algebra-over-local-field) didn't receive an answer on MathSE.

Let $K$ be a $p$-adic field, or more generally a local field. Let $D$ be a $d^2$-dimensional division algebra over $K$. Then $D$ is necessarily of the form $D = \bigoplus_{i=0}^{d-1} Le^i$, where $L$ is the unique unramified extension of $K$ of degree $d$, and $e^d =a$ for some $a \in L$. The Hasse invariant $\operatorname{inv}_K(D)$ of $D$ is equal to $\frac{1}{d}\operatorname{ord}_L(a) \in \frac{1}{d} \mathbb Z/\mathbb Z$.

Now let $D'$ be a central subalgebra of $D$. It is necessarily a division algebra over $K$. I believe one can use the primary decomposition of $D$ to show that $\dim_K D' = d'^2$ for some $d' \mid d$.

I'm wondering: how is the Hasse invariant of $D'$ related to the Hasse invariant of $D$?

A comment to my original question mentioned that a subalgebra of $D$ need not be central. I'm content to restrict to central subalgebras, but I'd be interested to know if anything can be said about subalgebras with larger centres too.

Comment: You retained a typo from the MSE post: $e^n = a$ should be $e^d = a$.  And why in the world are you using $e$ for two completely different purposes in paragraphs 1 and 2? Change that.

Comment: @KConrad Thank you very much for the suggestion; I've fixed the notation now.

Comment: I don't think that it is true that $\dim_K D$ in the second paragraph, corrected to $\dim_K D'$ as it should surely be, is a square.  Consider, for example, $d = 2$ and $D' = L$.

Comment: @LSpice I think you're correct and the statement applies only to central subalgebras.

Comment: @gimothytowers Your formula for the Hasse invariant is not correct. You may assume that $e=\pi_D$ is a uniformizer of $D$ that normalizes $L$. Then the map $l\mapsto \pi_D l\pi_D^{-1}$ is a power $\varphi^r$ of the Frobenius $\varphi$ of $L/K$. Then the Hasse invariant is $r/d$ mod ${\mathbb Z}$.